# How to make a UIButton to toggle like UISwitch in Swift with animation similar to UISwitch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, xcode8.2

I wish to make a custom UIButton with animation similar to the UISwitch while toggling On and Off.

```
    -(void) addToggleButton {
    CGRect aframe = CGRectMake(0,0,100,100);

    UIImage *selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected"];
    UIImage *unselectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected"];

    self.toggleUIButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:aframe];
    [self.toggleUIButton setImage:unselectedImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.toggleUIButton setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [self.toggleUIButton addTarget:self 
                            action:@selector(clickToggle:) 
                  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self addSubview:self.toggleUIButton];
}

-(void) clickToggle:(id) sender {
    BOOL isSelected = [(UIButton *)sender isSelected];
    [(UIButton *) sender setSelected:!isSelected];
}
```

Above is the code which i am planning to execute but please tell how to achieve the UISwitch animation while using two UIButtons side by side.

Comment: Show us your tried ?

Comment: the tried code is above but it not so perfect as the UISwitch animation

Comment: I don't think so that you will achieve that type of animation with UIbutton with above code when you tap button it will change image from selected to unselected and vice versa

Comment: Jessica, why r u not using UISwitch. No issue u r a beginner. Just go & search on cocoacontrol what r u looking e.g. https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=switch